# Angular 11 showing invalid date when trying to edit date in reactive forms

Tags: c#, css, angular

I am developing an application in net 5 and angular 11, and dates are causing me some problems. Everything works fine when I try to create new date, but when I try to edit the existing one, my input box is showing - invalid date. Moreover, I can create new date despite that message, but would really like to avoid the aforementioned message, I would to begin with be fine even with a simple message stated in the placeholder. Here is my code, thank you in advance everyone for your willingness to help me, and please accept my appologies if my question is not precise enough, still learning how to ask a proper question:):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PatientAppointmentsService } from 'src/app/patient-appointments/patient- 
appointments.service';
import { IAppointmentSingle, INewAppointmentToCreateOrEdit } from 
'src/app/shared/models/appointment';
import { AppointmentsService } from '../appointments.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-appointment-edit',
templateUrl: './appointment-edit.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./appointment-edit.component.scss']
})
export class AppointmentEditComponent implements OnInit {
appointmentForms: FormArray = this.fb.array([]);
officeList = [];
id: number;
appointmentnew: INewAppointmentToCreateOrEdit;
appointment: IAppointmentSingle;
errors: string[] = [];


 constructor(private appointmentsService: AppointmentsService,
          private patientappointmentsService: PatientAppointmentsService,
          private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
          private router: Router,
          private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
this.appointmentsService.getOffices()
.subscribe(res => this.officeList = res as []);

this.patientappointmentsService.getApointmentForEdit(this.id).subscribe(
(appointment: INewAppointmentToCreateOrEdit) => {
this.appointmentForms.push(this.fb.group({
          id: [this.id],
          office1Id: [appointment.office1Id, Validators.required],
          patient1Id: [appointment.patient1Id, Validators.required],
          startDateAndTimeOfAppointment: [appointment.startDateAndTimeOfAppointment, 
 Validators.required],
          endDateAndTimeOfAppointment: [appointment.endDateAndTimeOfAppointment, 
 Validators.required],
          remarks: [appointment.remarks],
          status: [appointment.status, Validators.required]
        }));
  });
  }

 recordSubmit(fg: FormGroup) {
  this.appointmentsService.editAppointment(fg.value).subscribe(
    (res: any) => {
     this.router.navigateByUrl('appointments');
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errors = error.errors;
      });
    }
```

And my template:

```
    <form [formGroup]="fg" *ngFor="let fg of appointmentForms.controls" 
   (submit)="recordSubmit(fg)"> 
            <input formControlName="id" id="id" class="form-control" hidden> 
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">           
                   <input type="text"
                   formControlName= "endDateAndTimeOfAppointment"
                   placeholder="End"
                   class="form-control"
                   bsDatepicker
                   [bsConfig]="{
                    containerClass: 'theme-green',
                    dateInputFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY  HH:mm'
                  }">
                 </div>       
             </div>   
    <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">    
                    <label style="font-size: small;"><strong>Special Remarks:</strong></label>       
                    <textarea type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    formControlName="remarks"
                    rows="4 " readonly="readonly"></textarea>
                 </div>      
             </div>   
              <div class="form-group text-center">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" value='true' formControlName='status'> Accept
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" value='false' formControlName='status' class="ml-3"> 
 Reject
                </label>
            </div>
   <div class="row" *ngIf="errors?.length > 0">
                <ul class="text-danger">
                    <li *ngFor="let error of errors">
                        {{error}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        
            <div class="peki form-group text-center">
                <button [disabled]='!fg.valid' class="btn btn-success mr-2" 
    type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

So instead showing "End" like it is stated in placeholoder, I get invalid date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace those lines
(Component)

---

```
startDateAndTimeOfAppointment: [new Date(appointment.startDateAndTimeOfAppointment), Validators.required],
endDateAndTimeOfAppointment: [new Date(appointment.endDateAndTimeOfAppointment), Validators.required],
```

---

(Template)

---

```
[bsConfig]="{ containerClass: 'theme-green', dateInputFormat: 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a' }"
```

---

Comment: thanks for suggestion, it doesn't work, but I managed to extract value by adding to DateString, like this:               endDateAndTimeOfAppointment: [appointment.endDateAndTimeOfAppointment.toDateString, Validators.required],

Comment: Hi, a little bit of explanation on how your solution solves the problem and maybe a little how it works, would be much appreciated. It would be great if you could edit the answer to add such explanation.

Comment: well, now I no longer see the message - invalid date, but am able to see the message I attach to the placeholder. Wish somebody would explain me why is this so now and not before, because this was a lucky punch...

Comment: The toDateString() method converts the date (not the time) of a Date object into a readable string.   https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp

Comment: after all, it seems that the answer provided by Mahmood works, mine is not good, so everyone reading this, please take that into account...thanks Mahmood!

Comment: Hi Tobias Theel! - Actually, Sardelic was getting both properties in String type, not in Date Object, That's why it was showing invalid. I just converted the String into Date Object by using Date Constructor "new Date()".